# Creating XSD Dynamically

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have two inputs. I get as input one XML file. I have to create an XSD file for this XML file. This XML file has tags which depend on another input. But that XML file should have certain tags for sure. For example, the XML file has the following structure : 
`<A>

<B>

<C>...</C>

<D>...</D>

<E>

<F>...</F>

<G>...</G>

</E>

</B>

</A>`


Here, in this XML file, A,B and E tags should be compulsory. But the tags C and D inside the B tag and tags F and G inside the E tag depends on another input. So I should create an XSD dynamically(i know that A,B and E tags should be present and I do know about the other tags from the other input) and validate the input XML file against the XML Schema. Can someone tell me how I can do this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're asking.

An XSD is a blue-print for constructing a business-valid XML document. You do not generally create XSD documents dynamically. You obtain an XSD document so that you can create an XML document that will be valid in a specific business usage or validate XML documents against that schema.

I'm know XML Serialization in C# is covered in great depth on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at XSLT yet? It's very useful for creating one XML file based on another. If you can access an XSLT engine from C# (I *guess* that's possible), I can help you set up the XSLT stylesheet.